# Align \boxed{} equation inside systeme*

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, highlighting, systeme

I would like to know how can I align a *systeme** environment with only a \boxed{} equation belonging to it.

The code I have produces the right system of equations, but the boxed equation is displaced.

I tried using the *emph* package, but it does emphasize the whole system of equations, and I don't want that.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,oneside]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{float} 

\begin{document}


    \begin{equation}

    \left\{(\bar 6\oplus 3)\otimes(6\oplus\bar 3)\right\}_c = 
    \systeme*{\;6\otimes\bar6=1\oplus 8\oplus 27, \;6\otimes 3=8\oplus                          10, \bar 3\otimes\bar 6=8\oplus\bar{10}, \boxed{\bar 3\otimes 3=1\oplus  8}\hspace{1mm}}

      \label{eq:15}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `systeme` is the right tool.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,oneside]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\{(\bar 6\oplus 3)\otimes(6\oplus\bar 3)\}_c =
\left\{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$0$}
\begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l@{}>{{}}l}
6\otimes\bar6 &= 1\oplus 8 &\hspace{-\dimen0}\oplus 27 \\
6\otimes 3    &= 8\oplus 10 \\
\bar 3\otimes\bar 6 &= 8\oplus\bar{10} \\
\cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|r@{}}{\bar 3\otimes 3} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}>{{}}l|}{= 1\oplus  8} \\
\cline{1-2}
\end{array}
\right.
\label{eq:15}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution with `tikzmark` (you need to compile twice, the first time, for seeing the box).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,oneside]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=1.2\ht\strutbox,xshift=-3pt]{pic cs:start}) 
  rectangle ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-\dp\strutbox]{pic cs:end});
\end{tikzpicture}
\{(\bar 6\oplus 3)\otimes(6\oplus\bar 3)\}_c =
\left\{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l}
6\otimes\bar6 &= 1\oplus 8 \oplus 27 \\
6\otimes 3    &= 8\oplus 10 \\
\bar 3\otimes\bar 6 &= 8\oplus\bar{10} \\
\tikzmark{start}\bar 3\otimes 3 & = 1\oplus  8\tikzmark{end} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\label{eq:15}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]